# How to populate a DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a DataGrid, one of the columns is a DataGridComboBoxColumn:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="User Name" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding UName}"/>
           <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Country" Width="Auto" ????/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

I have a Country class:

```
public class Country{
  public string name {get; set;}
  public string des {get; set;}
  public Country() {}
  public Country(string n, string d) {
      this.name = n;
      this.des = d;
  }
}
```

they have a name and a description, I want the names(of multiple Country objects) to populate the combo-box(and the des the tooltip of each combo-box option), how do I do that?

Note: later I would like to give the user the ability to add a new Country, so I would like the combo-box to change as well(to include the new Country), meaning the solution needs to allow that.

Note2: I am not using the MVVM pattern. edit: meaning it is not a duplicate.

Comment: how does this solve my problem? I am not using the MVVM pattern, so this: ConnectionViewModel vm = new ConnectionViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
doesn't really help me.

Comment: Add a name to your column .In code behind,Create a list of countries & assign to its ItemsSource.

Comment: this shows up as the object, I want just the names, also: I have a class named "User" which is the itemSource for the rest of the columns in the datagrid(in the example above - the user name), each user has a Name and Country, will doing what you suggested make it so that when a user changes the Country in the combobox, the value of the Country attribute in the User instance will change as well?

Comment: Set the selectedValuePath,DisplayValuePath & SelectedValueBinding for the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
 1. XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn     Header="User UName" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding UName}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColumn" Header="Country" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding CountryData}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

2. Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitData();
        ComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = CountriesCollection;
        DataGrid.ItemsSource = UsersCollection;
    }

    private void InitData()
    {
        UsersCollection = new ObservableCollection<UserData>(new List<UserData>
        {
            new UserData
            {
                UName = "Greg",
            },
            new UserData
            {
                UName = "Joe",
            },
             new UserData
            {
                UName = "Iv",
            }
        });
        CountriesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Country>(new List<Country>
        {
            new Country("Ger", "1500"),
            new Country("Fra", "1500"),
            new Country("Ru", "1500"),
            new Country("Bel", "1500"),
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Country> CountriesCollection { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<UserData> UsersCollection { get; set; }
}
```

3. User model:

```
 public class UserData
{
    public string UName { get; set; }

    public object CountryData { get; set; }
}
```

4. tool tip support: replace a desired combo box column with next xaml code:

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColumn" Header="Country" DisplayMemberPath="CountryName"
                                    ItemsSource="{StaticResource CountriesArray}" Width="Auto"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding CountryData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
                                    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soDataGridProjectsHelpAttempt:UserData}">
                                            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                                                <system:String x:Key="NoAnyEntriesKey">
                                                    No any entry presented
                                                </system:String>
                                            </DataTemplate.Resources>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryData.Description, FallbackValue={StaticResource NoAnyEntriesKey}}"></TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

and take in account you nedd to extend Country model with description property.

regards,

Comment: Thank you. 
In the Country Object I have a name field(which now is in view in the datagridcombobox) and a short description, how can I bind the description of each country in the datagridcombobox to a tooltip? (the desired effect is: a user hovers over an option in the combobox and sees the description field of that Country object as a tooltip)

Comment: @Stacker check this out.

Comment: I'm using WPF, I get "UserData is not supported in WPF" error on "DataType="{x:Type soDataGridProjectsHelpAttempt:UserData}""

Comment: But, I managed to do it(with your help): I just didn't use the DataTemplate, I set the value to the correct binding(CountryData.Description), thank you.